# Your balance: . lumens

Tags: assets, accounts, token, ledger, wallets

Can someone tell me why my balance just says .lumens?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same.

**Update:** Found the answer on a redit page: https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/comments/f47o07/ledger_nano_and_account_viewer_doesnt_show_balance/
The latest ledger update is to blame, they are working on it. Check your balance on the Stellar blockchain explorer : https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/

using your public key in the search at the top right.